# treeview control problem

Tags: c#

hi i am using a treeview control in my application i want to checked all child node by clicking on the parent node .how can i do this task

Comment: Where are you stuck? I don't have code at hand.. however looping over children of a node and toggling the Checked property should be simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best that you take a look at the documentation for [`TreeView`.AfterCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck.aspx) in MSDN.  The example provided performs exactly the function you are asking for, protects against a few common edge cases, and it's heavily commented.